# Qual è il significato di "escuriale"?

Tags: word-meaning

Nel romanzo *Diceria dell'untore*, di Gesualdo Bufalino, ho letto:

> Poiché veramente la Rocca, a guardarla così a fil di terreno, obesa
>   e nana dietro una schiera di palme, sembrava ben altro
>   dall’**escuriale** in fiamme che m’era apparso fra le sbarre
>   del cancello, quel tramonto in cui una carrozza mi ci
>   aveva deposto davanti; ma faceva pensare a una carogna
>   d’animale o di monumento, dalla cui epidermide uno spurgo di doratura colava, lasciando che, sotto, tutti i
>   dissesti e le carie dello scheletro si denudassero ad uno
>   ad uno.

Potreste spiegarmi cos'è un "escuriale?  Non ho trovato questo vocabolo in nessuno dei dizionari che ho consultato.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parla dell'[Escorial](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monastero_dell%27Escorial) ovvero della residenza dei re di Spagna, "*escuriale*" mi sembra un'italianizzazione della parola.

Vedi anche:
http://ricerca.repubblica.it/repubblica/archivio/repubblica/2009/11/26/escuriale.html

Qui viene usato secondo me come sinonimo di palazzo molto grande e monumentale.

Answer (score 4):

In [questo articolo](http://ricerca.repubblica.it/repubblica/archivio/repubblica/2009/11/26/escuriale.html) puoi trovare che l'***Escuriale*** è citato nell'opera "Escuriale, ovvero il palazzo dei buffoni" del belga Michel De Ghelderode, che fa riferimento al [Monastero dell'Escorial](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monastero_dell%27Escorial):

> "Escuriale", dal nome della residenza regale di Filippo di Spagna, è
>   un racconto scritto nel ' 27 dall' autore belga che indaga i rapporti
>   di forza tra re e popolo, sovrano e cortigiani, ma è anche la tragica
>   parabola del gioco delle parti: la storia è quella di un re dissennato
>   (Nicola Rignanese) che gioca a scambiarsi il ruolo col buffone di
>   corte Folial (Rosanna Gentili), a sua volta segretamente innamorato
>   della regina che sta per morire, sullo sfondo di un palazzo regale in
>   decadenza.

Nel contesto da te citato il termine viene utilizzato per fare riferimento ad un palazzo che sembrava essere sontuoso ed invece ad uno sguardo più attento mostra tutti i segni del dissesto.

Inoltre il riferimento alla carogna di animale sottolinea ulteriormente la decadenza del luogo descritto dall'autore.